# Hover background behind title

Tags: html, css, image, hover, mouseover

I am looking for help on the hover background I would like the background color to appear behind the title when the mouse hovers over it. I would also like the title to remain fixed so that it appears on the hover as well as when it is not on the hover so you can tell what the title of the gallery image is. I would like the color opacity to remain at a lighter opacity as well instead of a solid color so that way when you mouse over the image it creates a unique effect that allows the font and button appear after you hover over it. If I need to post more html and Css please let me know and I will post it .

Image without Hover
[image: Image without Hover]

Image on Hover
[image: Image on Hover]

```css
.view {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 10px solid #909090;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("../images/over1.jpg");
  border-radius: 50%;
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  max-width: 30.26%;
 height: 300px;
}

.view .mask,
.view .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

.view h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background:#000000;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.view p {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
  font-family: Merriweather, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow:
  -1px -1px 0 #000,
  1px -1px 0 #000,
  -1px 1px 0 #000,
  1px 1px 0 #000;

}

.view a.info {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Raleway, serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

.view a.info:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000
}


/*1*/

.view-first img {
  /*1*/
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-first .mask  {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 opacity: 0;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,4,0.57);
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 height: 100%; 
 
}

.view-first h2 {
  transform: translateY(1px);
  opacity: 100;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

}
.view-first p {
  transform: translateY(100px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-first a.info {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


/* */

.view-first:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.view-first:hover .mask {
 display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.view-first:hover h2,
.view-first:hover p,
.view-first:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.view-first:hover p {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.view-first:hover a.info {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

/*Print Design */
.view1 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 10px solid #909090;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("../images/over2.jpg");
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30.26%;
  height: 300px;
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}

.view1 .mask1,
.view1 .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

.view1 h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background:#000000; 
  margin: 50px 0 0 0
}

.view1 p {
  font-family: Merriweather, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow:
  -1px -1px 0 #000,
  1px -1px 0 #000,
  -1px 1px 0 #000,
  1px 1px 0 #000;

}

.view1 a.info {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Raleway, serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

.view1 a.info:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000
}


/*1*/

.view-second img {
  /*1*/
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-second .mask1 {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(4,10,255,0.64);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  height: 400px;
}

.view-second h2 {
  transform: translateY(1px);
  opacity: 100;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.view-second p {
  transform: translateY(100px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-second a.info {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


/* */

.view-second:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.view-second:hover .mask1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.view-second:hover h2,
.view-second:hover p,
.view-second:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.view-second:hover p {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.view-second:hover a.info {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

/*Package Design */
.view2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 10px solid #909090;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("../images/over3.jpg");
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30.26%;
  height: 300px;
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;

}

.view2 .mask2,
.view2 .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

.view2 h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 27px;
  padding: 10px;
  background:#000000; 
  margin: 50px 0 0 0
}

.view2 p {
  font-family: Merriweather, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow:
  -1px -1px 0 #000,
  1px -1px 0 #000,
  -1px 1px 0 #000,
  1px 1px 0 #000;

}

.view2 a.info {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Raleway, serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

.view2 a.info:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000
}


/*1*/

.view-third img {
  /*1*/
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-third .mask2 {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(17,155,6,0.79);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  height: 400px;
}

.view-third h2 {
  transform: translateY(1px);
  opacity: 100;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.view-third p {
  transform: translateY(100px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-third a.info {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


/* */

.view-third:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.view-third:hover .mask2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.view-third:hover h2,
.view-third:hover p,
.view-third:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.view-third:hover p {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.view-third:hover a.info {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

/* Website Design*/
.view3 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 10px solid #909090;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("../images/over4.jpg");
  border-radius: 50%;
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  width: 30.26%;
  height: 300px;
}

.view3 .mask3,
.view3 .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

.view3 h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 27px;
  padding: 10px;
  background:#000000;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

.view3 p {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
  font-family: Merriweather, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow:
  -1px -1px 0 #000,
  1px -1px 0 #000,
  -1px 1px 0 #000,
  1px 1px 0 #000;

}

.view3 a.info {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Raleway, serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

.view3 a.info:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000
}


/*1*/

.view-fourth img {
  /*1*/
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-fourth .mask3 {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,219,1,0.70);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  height: 100%; 
 
 
}

.view-fourth h2 {
  transform: translateY(1px);
  opacity: 100;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.view-fourth p {
  transform: translateY(100px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-fourth a.info {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


/* */

.view-fourth:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.view-fourth:hover .mask3 {
 display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.view-fourth:hover h2,
.view-fourth:hover p,
.view-fourth:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.view-fourth:hover p {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.view-fourth:hover a.info {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
/*UI/UX Design */
.view4 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 10px solid #909090;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("../images/over5.jpg");
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30.26%;
  height: 300px;
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}

.view4 .mask4,
.view4 .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

.view4 h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background:#000000; 
  margin: 50px 0 0 0
}

.view4 p {
  font-family: Merriweather, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow:
  -1px -1px 0 #000,
  1px -1px 0 #000,
  -1px 1px 0 #000,
  1px 1px 0 #000;

}

.view4 a.info {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Raleway, serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

.view4 a.info:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000
}


/*1*/

.view-fifth img {
  /*1*/
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-fifth .mask4 {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(247,143,5,0.77);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  height: 400px;
}

.view-fifth h2 {
  transform: translateY(1px);
  opacity: 100;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.view-fifth p {
  transform: translateY(100px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-fifth a.info {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


/* */

.view-fifth:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.view-fifth:hover .mask4 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.view-fifth:hover h2,
.view-fifth:hover p,
.view-fifth:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.view-fifth:hover p {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.view-fifth:hover a.info {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
/*Graphic Art */
.view5 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 10px solid #909090;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("../images/over6.jpg");
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30.26%;
  height: 300px;
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;

}

.view5 .mask5,
.view5 .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

.view5 h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background:#000000; 
  margin: 50px 0 0 0
}

.view5 p {
  font-family: Merriweather, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow:
  -1px -1px 0 #000,
  1px -1px 0 #000,
  -1px 1px 0 #000,
  1px 1px 0 #000;

}

.view5 a.info {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Raleway, serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

.view5 a.info:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000
}


/*1*/

.view-sixth img {
  /*1*/
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-sixth .mask5 {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(70,1,180,0.82);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  height: 400px;
}

.view-sixth h2 {
  transform: translateY(1px);
  opacity: 100;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.view-sixth p {
  transform: translateY(100px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-sixth a.info {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


/* */

.view-sixth:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.view-sixth:hover .mask5 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.view-sixth:hover h2,
.view-sixth:hover p,
.view-sixth:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.view-sixth:hover p {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.view-sixth:hover a.info {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

/*Projects */
.view6 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 10px solid #909090;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("../images/over7.jpg");
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30.26%;
  height: 300px;
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;

}

.view6 .mask6,
.view6 .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

.view6 h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background:#000000; 
  margin: 50px 0 0 0
}

.view6 p {
  font-family: Merriweather, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow:
  -1px -1px 0 #000,
  1px -1px 0 #000,
  -1px 1px 0 #000,
  1px 1px 0 #000;

}

.view6 a.info {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Raleway, serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

.view6 a.info:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000
}


/*1*/

.view-seventh img {
  /*1*/
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-seventh .mask6 {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(25,177,220,0.74);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  height: 400px;
}

.view-seventh h2 {
  transform: translateY(1px);
  opacity: 100;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.view-seventh p {
  transform: translateY(100px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-seventh a.info {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


/* */

.view-seventh:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.view-seventh:hover .mask6 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.view-seventh:hover h2,
.view-seventh:hover p,
.view-seventh:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.view-seventh:hover p {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.view-seventh:hover a.info {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
/*Services */
.view7 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 10px solid #909090;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("../images/over8.jpg");
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30.26%;
  height: 300px;
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;

}

.view7 .mask7,
.view7 .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

.view7 h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background:#000000; 
  margin: 50px 0 0 0
}

.view7 p {
  font-family: Merriweather, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow:
  -1px -1px 0 #000,
  1px -1px 0 #000,
  -1px 1px 0 #000,
  1px 1px 0 #000;

}

.view7 a.info {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Raleway, serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

.view7 a.info:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000
}


/*1*/

.view-eighth img {
  /*1*/
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-eighth .mask7 {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(188,139,4,0.72);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  height: 400px;
}

.view-eighth h2 {
  transform: translateY(1px);
  opacity: 100;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.view-eighth p {
  transform: translateY(100px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-eighth a.info {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


/* */

.view-eighth:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.view-eighth:hover .mask7 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.view-eighth:hover h2,
.view-eighth:hover p,
.view-eighth:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.view-eighth:hover p {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.view-eighth:hover a.info {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
/*Photo and Video */
.view8 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 10px solid #909090;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("../images/over9.jpg");
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30.26%;
  height: 300px;
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;

}

.view8 .mask8,
.view8 .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

.view8 h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background:#000000; 
  margin: 50px 0 0 0
}

.view8 p {
  font-family: Merriweather, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow:
  -1px -1px 0 #000,
  1px -1px 0 #000,
  -1px 1px 0 #000,
  1px 1px 0 #000;

}

.view8 a.info {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Raleway, serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

.view8 a.info:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000
}


/*1*/

.view-nineth img {
  /*1*/
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-nineth .mask8 {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(19,214,118,0.75);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  height: 400px;
}

.view-nineth h2 {
  transform: translateY(1px);
  opacity: 100;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.view-nineth p {
  transform: translateY(100px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-nineth a.info {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


/* */

.view-nineth:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.view-nineth:hover .mask8 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.view-nineth:hover h2,
.view-nineth:hover p,
.view-nineth:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.view-nineth:hover p {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.view-nineth:hover a.info {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="section group">
 <div class="view view-first">
 <h2>LOGOS</h2>
 <div class="mask">
      <p>The Beginning Part Of The Branding Process.Logos I Have Done For Clients</p>
      <a href="#" class="info">Click Here</a>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="view1 view-second">
 <h2>PRINT DESIGN</h2>
    <div class="mask1">
      <p>Flyers, Pamphlets, Business Cards And More. Print Marketing For Clients</p>
      <a href="#" class="info">Click Here</a>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="view2 view-third">
 <h2>PACKAGE DESIGN</h2>
    <div class="mask2">
      <p>Package Design And Engineering For Marketing And Consumption For Clients</p>
      <a href="#" class="info">Click Here</a>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="view3 view-fourth">
 <h2>WEBSITE DESIGN</h2>
    <div class="mask3">
      <p>Websites, Email Blasts And Other Programing Using HTML, CSS, Javascipt Etc.</p>
      <a href="#" class="info">Click Here</a>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="view4 view-fifth">
 <h2>UI/UX DESIGN</h2>
    <div class="mask4">
      <p>User Interface And User Experience Design For Mobile, Tablet, Web, Etc.</p>
      <a href="#" class="info">Click Here</a>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="view5 view-sixth">
 <h2>GRAPHIC ART</h2>
    <div class="mask5">
      <p>Digital And Traditional Art Using Font, Graphics, And Other Methods</p>
      <a href="#" class="info">Click Here</a>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="view6 view-seventh">
 <h2>PROJECTS</h2>
    <div class="mask6">
      <p>Current Projects I Am Working On For Clients And Personal </p>
      <a href="#" class="info">Click Here</a>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="view7 view-eighth">
 <h2>SERVICES</h2>
    <div class="mask7">
      <p>My Skillset And Tasks I Can Do As Well As The Programs I Use</p>
      <a href="Services.html" class="info">Click Here</a>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="view8 view-nineth">
 <h2>PHOTO & VIDEO</h2>
    <div class="mask8">
      <p>Photo Editing, Video Editing, Presentation Design And Production</p>
      <a href="#" class="info">Click Here</a>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey @cambam88, i am not able to understand you can you provide a image that shows what you want.. Thanks

Comment: @sbrrk Hey i attached image links to the end of my post so  it can give a better understanding of what im looking for , also if you run the code snippet i think it gives an example of what my coding is like. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

According to your problem statement and my understanding this might help you

```
.section > div h2 {
     text-transform: uppercase;
     text-decoration: underline;
     border: 1px solid #000000;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     font-weight: 900;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 30px;
     padding: 10px;
     transition:all 0.3s linear;
     background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
     margin: 50px 0 0 0;
     overflow: hidden;
}
.section > div:hover h2 {
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.7),rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
}
```

use rgba color format for opacity background